# Volley Tutorial - getCacheDir() - Cannot resolve method

Tags: java, android, android-volley

In this link: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html

Title: Set Up a Network and Cache

It defines cache like this:

```
Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024);
```

I searched for 30 mins now, I try to import android.content.Context but still getting the error: Cannot resolve method.

My code:

```
class NetworkActivity{
String url;

RequestQueue networkRequest;
Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024);
Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
...
```

I don't know if I extend something because it says nothing on the example.

Here is my imports:

```
import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Network;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;
```

Comment: So, I need to define a Context object and call it like "mContext.getCacheDir()"?

Comment: see my answer probably help u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getCacheDir](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()) method is from `Context` class so you need to use valid `Context` to access it.

Use `NetworkActivity` class constructor to get Context :

```
public class NetworkActivity{
    private Context mContext;
    Cache cache;
    NetworkActivity(Context mContext){
        this.mContext=mContext;
        this.cache = new DiskBasedCache(mContext.getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024);
    }
}
```

Pass Context as if using Activity :

```
NetworkActivity objNetworkActivity=new NetworkActivity(ClassName.this);
```

or if using `Fragment` then use `getActivity()`.